# Is there a way to immediately use a single of multiple return values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm splitting a string into two of which I know for certain, the 2nd one will be the representation of an integer. I want to unpack both values and immediately cast the 2nd value to int. Basically I want this code in one line:

```
a, b = x.split('foo')
b = int(b)
```

I searched the web among SO, but looking for something containing `python multiple return values` only returns sites explaining *how to return multiple values at once*. Then I came up with that:

```
a, b = [value if i == 0 else int(value) for i, value in enumerate(f())]
```

but that's an abomination I'd like to avoid.

**So is there a way to actually cast one of multiple return values of a function *on the fly*?**

Comment: I think the first bit of code that you're trying to avoid is as neat as you're going to get. It's succinct and clear. The fact that it's over two lines really isn't an issue.

Comment: Not possible but you can try something like `x, y = "1 2".split()[0], int("1 2".split()[1])`, doesn't look too good

Comment: `a, b = x.split('foo'); b = int(b)`… That’s just about as short as any other solution…

Comment: `a, b = x.split('foo')[0],int(x.split('foo')[1])`. One-liners are not necessarily 'better', by the way.

Comment: `I want this code in one line` - why?

Comment: @wwii for two reasons: 1st I want to see, if there's a language feature I'm just missing here; 2nd I use this in a parsing statement (many `if`s) very often, since under some conditions, I manipulate the `int` variable. I want to compress it a little bit for readability.
@usr2564301 I know ^^ That's why I ask, if there's maybe a language feature, I'm missing here.

Comment: If you absolutely need this to be a compact one liner, why not define a function to do the splitting and conversion to int and return the pieces? The definition will take up room elsewhere, and you can have your one liner `a, b = func(‘foo’)`

Comment: @schwartz721 I guess, this will be what I'll end up doing. I wanted to learn something I may had missed, since I'm still pretty new to python and haven't learned (and incorporated) many of its features, yet.

Comment: @schwartz721 do you want to make your comment an answer? Since nobody else did so far and it's of course one solution to the problem. Also I in fact ended up doing it that way, to ensure maintainability and extensibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a short one-liner to make your code readable, compact, and neat, defining your own function is a good option. The definition of the function can take up space elsewhere (even in a module), while your main script stays uncluttered.

```py
def str_int(my_string):
    a, b = my_string.split()
    b = int(b)
    return a, b
```

Then the call to this function is a short one-liner.
`a, b = str_int(my_string)`

Answer (score 1):

One more option with list comprehension:

```
x = 'test 1'

a, b = [(a, int(b)) for a, b in [x.split()]][0]

print(type(a), a, type(b), b)
# output: <class 'str'> test <class 'int'> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function as below:

```
my_str = 'item 1'
a, b = map(lambda x : int(x) if x.isdigit() else x, my_str.split())
```

Comment: This is very nice. Comprehensible, extensible and more versatile on different inputs.

Comment: This can be made more readable by removing the map and lambda and using the same structure in a list comprehension.
`a, b = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in my_str.split()]`

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.8's assignment expressions you can use this abomination:

```
x = '4foobar'
a, b = int((y := x.split('foo'))[0]), y[1]
# a = 4, b = 'bar'
```

Though obviously this is convoluted and prone to error. Just use a two liner.